# "Undefined" updating or delete a fresh new comment using Ajax and Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

When i create a new comment it displays good but i can't edit it or delete, to do it i have to refresh the page first.. The reason? In console="Undefined".. when the whole html with the new comment data is regenerated once created, looks like it doesn't gives me the id of the new comment.. Like i said i have to refresh the page to edit or delete the new comments.

This is how i regenerate and create the new comments:

Ajax:

```
$('.send').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var dataSerialize = $('#add-comment').serialize();
   var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
   $.ajax({
      method: 'post',
      url: urlPostComment,
      data: dataSerialize,
      dataType: 'json', // <- La coma
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data); // <- Revisar JSON en la consola del navegador
         if( data.success )
         {
           $('#post-comments').append(
'<section class="comment-list'+data.id+'"><article class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><figure class="comment-list-image"><img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="/uploads/avatars/'+data.picture+'"/></figure></div><div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><header class="text-left"><div class="comment-user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> '+data.name+' '+data.lastname+' <time class="comment-date p-l-10"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '+data.timestamp+'</time></div></header><div id="comment-post" data-commentid="'+data.id+'"><p id="display-comment" class="store-comment p-t-10">'+data.comment+'</p></div></div><div class="panel-footer list-inline comment-footer"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="edit-comment" class="edit-comment" value="'+data.id+'" data-name="'+data.comment+'">Editar</a> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="delete-comment"class="delete-comment" data-id="'+data.id+'" data-name="'+ data.comment+'">Eliminar</a></div></div></div></article></section>'
          );

            toastr.success('Comentario enviado.', '', {timeOut: 7000})
            $('#comment-new').val('');

         }
         else {
           toastr.warning(" "+ data.message +" ", '', {timeOut: 7000})
         }

      }, // <- La coma
      error: function () {
        toastr.warning('No hemos podido enviar el comentario, intenta nevamente.', '', {timeOut: 7000})
      }, // <- La coma
      complete: function () {
        $btn.button('reset');
      }
   });
});
```

This is my create function in the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
{
  if(!$request->has('comment') || empty($request->comment))
  {
    return response()->json([
      'message' => 'No puedes enviar un comentario vacío.',
      'success' => false
    ]);
  }

  $post = Post::find($post_id);
  $comment = new Comment();
  $comment->comment   = $request->comment;
  $comment->approved  = true;
  $comment->user_id   = auth()->id();
  $comment->user->profilepic = $comment->user->profilepic;
  $comment->post_id   = $post_id;
  $comment->save();
  return response()->json([
    'comment' => $comment->comment,
    'user_id' => $comment->user_id,
    'post_id' => $comment->post_id,
    'picture' => $comment->user->profilepic,
    'name'    => $comment->user->name,
    'lastname' => $comment->user->last_name,
    'timestamp' => $comment->created_at->diffForHumans(),
    'post_slug' => $post->slug,
    'success' => true
  ]);
}
```

I wonder if there's a character limit when writing the new html. I get the whole code regenerated but i don't know, i needed to reduce some code lines because part of the code didn't get highlighted before..

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you are not using `document` in your javascript.
try this in all your ajax requests:

```
$(document).on('click', '.send', function(e){
    //your ajax code
});
```

and also update or delete methodes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e){
    //your ajax code
}); 

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e){
    //your ajax code
});
```

Comment: Well the problem is other now =P now i'm getting the "id" but i can edit or delete new comments, the problem is when i refresh, the original comment appears again and the deleted one.. so to delete them o edit them i need to refresh the page